Double Junction MS Contact
How can I deal with a double MS Junction?
the problem is there are thin Si sample with two metallic contacts on side. and the N type doping at Si is ND=1015cm-3 everywhere. Schottky barrier height of both MS junction is 0.7eV.
the problem asks me about when the Si Thickness going short (5μm, 1μm, at the limit), calculate the electron concentrations and E field at the center.
I tried to solve this problem by using Wdep length. At first case the 5μm length, space charge p = qND at (0<x<Wdep), and (5-Wdep<x<5). And by Schottky barrier height - Vt*ln(Nc/Nd) = 0.43 I found Built-in voltage. Use Built in V, calculate Wdep. It was 0.75μm. so, p = qND at (0<x<0.75, 4.25<x<5).
At this moment, it was all clear but I was confused about calculating Electric Field. Both charges are positive, and if I integrate it to find E field, the slope will be go up!
but I thought Emax shown at both junction.
Is there any mistake at my solution?
Also, if you can, let me know how to deal with 1μm and limit case.
